# Jmeter json extraction and removing the duplicates to write into a file

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

```js
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

def path = vars.get("BaseFilePath") + "/" + vars.get("FhirVersion") + "/Get/Patient/";
def newLine = System.getProperty('line.separator')
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

//address
def addressCSV = new File(path + 'address.csv')
def addressList = []
def addressCityCSV = new File(path + 'address-city.csv')
def cityList = []
def addressCountryCSV = new File(path + 'address-country.csv')
def countryList = []
def addressPostalCodeCSV = new File(path + 'address-postalcode.csv')
def postalCodeList = []
def addressStateCSV = new File(path + 'address-state.csv')
def stateList = []

def addressArray = JsonPath.read(response, '$..address')
addressArray.each { eachAddress ->
    eachAddress.each { subAddress ->
        subAddress.get('line').each { line ->
            addressList.add(line)
        }
  
  cityList.add(subAddress.get('city'))
  stateList.add(subAddress.get('state'))
  postalCodeList.add(subAddress.get('postalCode'))
  countryList(subAddress.get('country'))    
    }

addressList.unique().each { address ->
 addressCSV << address << newLine 
 }
cityList.unique().each { city ->
 addressCityCSV << city << newLine 
 }
countryList.unique().each { country ->
 addressCountryCSV << country << newLine
 }
postalCodeList.unique().each { postalCode ->
 addressPostalCodeCSV << postalCode << newLine
 }
stateList.unique().each { state ->
 addressStateCSV << state << newLine
 }
}
```

I wrote this scirpt in JSR223 post processor of jmeter, to extract data from json response, addressList, cityList and other lists contain duplicate elements so i wanted to remove the duplicates and push unique values into files.
But this code is not working. Can someone help me in fixing this

Comment: Did you meant to accept a different answer?

Comment: answer from dimitri T works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [Collection.unique()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique()) function should do the trick for you, i.e.

```
addressList = addressList.unique()
```

Demo:

[image]

However if your collection contains custom objects (i.e. not normal [Strings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html)) you will need to come up with a special [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation, i.e.

```
def myComparator = [
        equals: { delegate.equals(it) },
        compare: { source, target ->
            source.someField <=> target.someField
        }
] as Comparator

def unique = addressList.unique(myComparator)
```

See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) for more Groovy tips and tricks

Comment: unique is not working, im still getting duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

For keeping only unique values use [Set](http://grails.asia/groovy-set-examples)

> We can use the toSet() function to convert a List to a Set.

So you can add it on the relevant lists as:

```
 uniqueStateCSVSet = addressStateCSV.toSet()
```

Or predefine it, as

```
 Set addressArray
```